# Specifying non-default ports for a VM at the time of VM creation itself

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Whenever one creates a VM , it allows RDP on default port 3389. Changing this involves logging into the VM and changing firewall/registry settings. Isn't there an option by which at the time of the VM creation itself we can specify a custom port instead of the default port? Logging into the VM in order to change this means we can't basically specify it at the time of VM creation. The question is for RDP(default port#3389) but I am interested in specifying custom ports for arbitrary standard services like MS-SQL (default port#1433) etc. Talking about RDP/MS-SQL implies it's a Windows VM. But again it could be SSH(default port#22) for a Linux VM. Now depending on the OS of VM , one would have to adopt separate methods to specify custom ports for standard services. Instead of that, it would be great if Azure VM creation process itself allows us to specify this regardless of OS type we are choosing for the VM.

Comment: Yes, this can be done both via the portal or via ARM template. Have you walked through creating your VM via the portal? There are multiple steps (unless you skip them), one of which is networking and ports.

Comment: As @DavidMakogon said it is possible using a network security group. how are you deploying your vm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of methods you can create an Azure VM. Currently, It seems that you are only able to allow the default ports 80,443,22,3389 in the inbound port rules of NSG when you [create a VM via the Azure portal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal) If you want to expose additional ports in your NSG, you can use [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-powershell#create-virtual-machine) or [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-cli), or others. You can get more details about [how to guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp).

[image]

Besides, if you're interested in improving Azure Virtual Machines, you can post your voice [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines?query=nsg%20port).